# SQL Convert Top 1 row results to columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table with 10 columns and my query will give me only 1 record always.
Now i want to convert this single record to key value pair.

Ex: SELECT * FROM dbo.Table
OUTPUT:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4 col5
============================ 
val1 val2   val2  val4 val5
```

Expecting ouput as follows

```
name    value  
==============
col1     val1
col2     val2
col3     val3
col4     val4
col5     val5
```

Please suggest how to do this.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your columns are a) Fixed and b) of the same type, you can use [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) to achieve this translation:

```
select name, value
from MyTable
unpivot
(
  name
  for Value in ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4], [Col5])
) x;
```

[SqlFiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f295f/1)